# How do I use StyleGan?

Tags: machine-learning

There are no tutorials or instructions online for how to use `StyleGan`.  I have downloaded, read, and executed the code, and I just get a blinking white cursor.  Can you point me in the right direction?  Any instructions, or a course of study that might help me in my goal, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice step-by-step video tutorial for running StyleGAN on Google Collab:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwwyr7cOBlU

And here is the notebook to run StyleGAN and generate an image:
https://github.com/jeffheaton/present/blob/master/youtube/style_gan.ipynb

I guess, it could be adjusted to also run locally in Jupyter and also to display the image as cell output.